# Node.js listen to MongoDB change

Tags: mongodb, node.js, watch, listen

Is there a way for Node.js to listen to a change in a particular data in a collection of MongoDB, and fire an event if a change happens?

Comment: Where are you writing to the MongoDB store from? From only the node.js instance, or from multiple sources?

Comment: Well.. mongo is connected to node.js   however, people can manually change the data in mongo directly. (such as mongoHub)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB apparently now supports triggers and watch, this answer is outdated.

**[Original]** I believe you are looking for a [database trigger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_trigger).

Unfortunately, MongoDB has no support for them yet, so I don't think you can listen for changes directly from the database.  You'll need to setup some sort of notification system (e.g. pub/sub) that alerts interested parties when a collection has changed.

Comment: really hope triggers become available. They talked about them at the last MongoSF

Comment: There are triggers in [mongodb stitch](https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/triggers/)

Comment: MongoDB supports `.watch()` method.

Comment: Stackoverflow needs a way to "unaccept" your own accepted answer so that when things change better answers float to the top...

Answer (score 14):

Well, this is an old question, but I was struggling with the same thing.  I found a number of tidbits that helped me put together a solution, and I've published it as a library:

https://github.com/TorchlightSoftware/mongo-watch

The library is written in coffeescript.  Here's an example in javascript, for those that prefer.

```
var MongoWatch = require('mongo-watch'),
    watcher = new MongoWatch({parser: 'pretty'});

watcher.watch('test.users', function(event) {
  return console.log('something changed:', event);
});
```

Comment: Can you share more about the structure of the returned event from `watcher.watch(...)`

Answer (score 2):

MongoDB 3.6 introduced [change streams](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/), which are designed to solve precisely this problem.

Here's an example: https://github.com/thakkaryash94/mongodb-change-streams-nodejs-example

```
const pipeline = [
  {
    $project: { documentKey: false }
  }
];

const db = client.db("superheroesdb");
const collection = db.collection("superheroes");

const changeStream = collection.watch(pipeline);
// start listen to changes
changeStream.on("change", function (change) {
  console.log(change);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, kind of late. 

But still, if someone looking to notify the MongoDB changes to the node.js then they can use [mubsub](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mubsub) library.

This is active library and very easy to integrate with nodejs.
It uses Mongo's tailable cursors and capped collections.

It works in pub/sub fashion to notify the subscriber when the document inserted into the MongoDB.

Check on [Github](https://github.com/scttnlsn/mubsub) for details.