# Is it possible to show live data from MongoDB via socket.io?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, socket.io

So, I would like to stream live data from MongoDB to my web, and I really don't know how can I handle live connection by sockets.io. The data is pushed to database from  an external source but when I append the data on MongoDB compass nothing happened.

This is my code:

```
const mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

mongo.connect('', function (err,db) {

    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    console.log("Mongodb Connected...");

    io.on('connection', (socket) => {
        console.log("Someone connected.");

        Post.find().sort({_id:-1}).limit(1).lean().then(req =>{
            socket.emit('temp', {temp: req});
        })

    });

});
```

Comment: Look into mongodb's change streams

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7587756/node-js-listen-to-mongodb-change

Answer (score 2):

Few things to consider while working with real-time reports

- Connect your socket with server and client.
- When Something happened on the server (in your case when data insert into DB) emit event as you are already doing on the above code.
- Listen to your event from client side (browser) (You will get some signal or data from the server)
- Once your received particular signal (event) from the client side, Hit particular URL using ajax to get data from the server and display it as per your requirements.

I Hope it will help you to solve your problem.